# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for shopping cart$_SESSION['cart']

Tags: php, session

```
if (isset($_GET['addCart'])&& is_numeric($_GET['addCart']))
    {
        $item = $_GET['addCart'];

        $_SESSION ['cart'][$item] = $item;
        echo "<h3 class=change> Item ".$item." has been added to cart.</h3>";


        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $myItem)
            {

                echo "<br>item: ".$myItem."<br>";
            }

    }
```

I can't display the items in the shopping cart.
When I run this code, I get a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

**EDIT:**
However, this works fine:

```
$_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = array();
$_SESSION['shoppingCart']['1'] = 2;
$_SESSION['shoppingCart']['2'] = 3;

//get all items
foreach($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $item)
{
    echo"<br>contents of shoppingcart ".$item."<br>";
}
```

**EDIT**

Session is started.
I think it has to do with this line:

```
$_SESSION ['cart'][$item] = $item;
```

I tried these two and it doesn't work:

```
`$_SESSION ['cart']['$item'] = $item`; 
`$_SESSION ['cart'][] = $item`;
```

error for first one: Warning: Illegal string offset '$item'

error for second one: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Obviously a numeric value.

Comment: it is a simple user_id (an int) from a link.
<a href='?addCart=".$u->getUser_id()

Comment: did you start your session? `session_start();`

Comment: session was started.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is used for keyed arrays.  If `$_SESSION['cart']` is not a keyed array, use a `for` loop instead.

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['cart']);$i++){

echo "$_SESSION['cart'][$i]";

}
```

Comment: take out the quotes on cart, or you'll be producing T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE errors.

Comment: OPs `$_SESSION['cart']` has keyed arrays -> `$_SESSION ['cart'][$item] = $item;`. This would only work if OP did `$_SESSION ['cart'][] = $item;`

Comment: The foreach should work seeing as this works fine in my code:

$_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = array();

$_SESSION['shoppingCart']['1'] = 2;

$_SESSION['shoppingCart']['2'] = 3;


//get all items

foreach($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $item)


{

 
   echo"<br>contents of shoppingcart ".$item."<br>";

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on how your cart items are stored in $_SESSION['cart'] 
If $_SESSION['cart'] contains an array of items, you should do something like this:

```
$items = $_SESSION['cart'];

for($i=0; $i<count($items); $i++)
{
echo $items[$i].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: OP has `$_SESSION ['cart'][$item] = $item;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.

Please check if your php session config is ok. Use `phpinfo()` and check the `session.*` config, look for `session.save_path` - check if you have this director and your web server is able to write there.

Also try to put: `session_start();` at the beginnig of the script.

Comment: Session start was already started.  If I had a session_start() at top of the page, I get this warning message:
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Answer (score 0):

You should try initializing the cart index of the session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

Before you try to add items to it. Also be sure to start your session using the `session_start()` function